# I can't use Button if I extend TabActivity

Tags: android

I am trying to make two tabs. First tab is an `EditText` component then a `Button` component. I want that when I push the button on tab one, it will send text from my `EditText` component to the `TextView` component in tab two.

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity{
EditText boxnama;
EditText boxalamat;
Spinner tanggal;
Spinner bulan;
Spinner tahun;
RadioGroup rg;
RadioButton pria;
RadioButton wanita;
CheckBox basket;
CheckBox bola;
CheckBox robot;
Button ok;
TextView hasil;
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    boxnama = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.boxnama);
    boxalamat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.boxalamat);
    tanggal = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.tanggal);
    bulan = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.bulan);
    tahun = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.tahun);
    rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    pria = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.pria);
    wanita = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.wanita);
    basket = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.basket);
    bola = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.bola);
    robot = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.robot);
    hasil = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hasil);
    ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new click()); // error on this line, if i delete this line, my program run smoothly
                                        // but i won't have my button function

    LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, tabHost.getTabContentView(),true);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("TAB1").setIndicator("TAB1").setContent(R.id.tabsatu));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("TAB2").setIndicator("TAB2").setContent(R.id.tabdua));


}

public class click implements Button.OnClickListener{
    public void onClick(View v){
        //my code for button here
    }
}
```

and now here the logcat say

> 11-09 08:29:15.385: D/AndroidRuntime(826): Shutting down VM
>   11-09 08:29:15.385: W/dalvikvm(826): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tugas/com.example.tugas.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.TabActivity.ensureTabHost(TabActivity.java:140)
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.TabActivity.getTabHost(TabActivity.java:162)
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at com.example.tugas.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:32)
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
>   11-09 08:29:15.492: E/AndroidRuntime(826):  ... 11 more

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Please show the complete text and stack trace of the error.

Comment: TabActivity was deprecated in API 13, use TabLayout instead http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html

Comment: Are you sure you are using correct resource id that is assigned to button? The error is NullPointerException .